# Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{(a+b\cos(t))^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

For solving the iuntegral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{(a+b\cos(t))^2}$ I will make it a complex one using the substitusion: $e^{it}=z$ So the integral becomes:
$$\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{zdz}{(bz^2+2az+1)^2}=\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{zdz}{(z-z_1)^2(z-z_2)^2}$$
Where:
$$z_1=-\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b} ; z_2=-\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$$
We also have the condition: $a>b>0$ So only $z_2$ is inside the contour. I tried to find the only residue by the formula:
$$\text{Res}(f;z_2)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_2} \frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}((z-z_2)^mf(z))$$ $$m=2$$
$$\Rightarrow \text{Res}(f;z_2)=\lim_{z\to z_2}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z}{(z-z_1)^2}\right)$$
However In my textbook it says that:
$$\text{Res}(f;z_2)=\lim_{z\to z_2}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z}{b^2(z-z_1)^2}\right)$$
Where does that $b^2$ come from? I just can't understand.

Comment: Please fix your latex. you write `cos` instead of `\cos`

Comment: $$\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{dz}{(bz^2+2az+1)^2}=\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{dz}{(z-z_1)^2(z-z_2)^2}$$ is not correct, because where does b go?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4717370/686284

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not correct** that
$$
\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{dz}{(bz^2+2az+1)^2}=\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{dz}{(z-z_1)^2(z-z_2)^2},
$$
because it is **not correct** that
$$
bz^2+2az+1 = (z-z_1) (z - z_2).
$$

To see why it is not correct, compare the coefficients of $z^2$: the coefficient of $z^2$ on the left side is $b$, while that on the right side is $1$. They cannot be equal unless $b = 1$.

It is correct that
$$
bz^2+2az+1 = \color{red}{b} (z-z_1) (z - z_2).
$$

---

Well, there are still mistakes in your original post. I will solve the integral below.

Put $z = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$. We have
$$
\cos {t} = \frac{z^2 + 1}{2z}
$$
and
$$
z = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t} \implies \mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{i} z\, \mathrm{d}t
\implies \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{i}z}.
$$
Hence
$$
a + b \cos {t} = \frac{bz^2 + 2az + \color{red}{b}}{2z}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{(a + b \cos {t})^2} = \frac{4z^2}{(bz^2 + 2az + \color{red}{b})^2}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(a + b \cos {t})^2} \\
= {} & \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{i}z} \frac{4z^2}{(bz^2 + 2az + \color{red}{b})^2} \\
= {} & \frac{4}{\mathrm{i}\color{red}{b^2}} \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\color{red}{z}}{(z^2 + 2kz + 1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}{z} \\
= {} & \frac{4}{\mathrm{i}\color{red}{b^2}} \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\color{red}{z}}{(z - z_1)^2 (z - z_2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}{z},
\end{aligned}
$$
in which
$$
\begin{aligned}
& k = \frac{a}{b}, \\
& z_1 = -k - \sqrt{k^2 - 1}, \\
& z_2 = -k + \sqrt{k^2 - 1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $k > 1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_2
= {} & -(k - \sqrt{k^2 - 1}) \\
= {} & \frac{-(k - \sqrt{k^2 - 1})(k + \sqrt{k^2 - 1})}{k + \sqrt{k^2 - 1}} \\
= {} & \frac{-1}{k + \sqrt{k^2 - 1}}
\end{aligned}
$$
is in the interval $(-1, 0)$, and
$$
z_1 = -(k + \sqrt{k^2 - 1}) < -1.
$$
Hence only $z_2$ is inside the contour.

The residue is
$$
\mathrm{Res}(f;z_2)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_2} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{m-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{m-1}}((z-z_2)^mf(z)),
$$
in which $m = 2$ and
$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{(z - z_1)^2 (z - z_2)^2}.
$$
It is not hard to find that
$$
\mathrm{Res}(f;z_2) = -\frac{z_2 + z_1}{(z_2 - z_1)^3}
= \frac{k}{4 (k^2 - 1)^{3/2}}.
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(a + b \cos {t})^2} \\
= {} & \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{i}z} \frac{4z^2}{(bz^2 + 2az + b)^2} \\
= {} & \frac{4}{\mathrm{i}\color{red}{b^2}} \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\color{red}{z}}{(z^2 + 2kz + 1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}{z} \\
= {} & \frac{4}{\mathrm{i}\color{red}{b^2}} \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\color{red}{z}}{(z - z_1)^2 (z - z_2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}{z} \\
= {} &\frac{4}{\mathrm{i} b^2} \cdot 2\pi\mathrm{i} \cdot \frac{k}{4 (k^2 - 1)^{3/2}} \\
= {} & \frac{2\pi k}{b^2 (k^2 - 1)^{3/2}} \\
= {} & \frac{2\pi kb}{b^3 (k^2 - 1)^{3/2}} \\
= {} & \frac{2\pi a}{(b^2)^{3/2} (k^2 - 1)^{3/2}} \\
= {} & \frac{2\pi a}{(a^2 - b^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One mistake has been pointed out by @Juliamisto

Another mistake is

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{(a+b\cos(t))^2}=\frac{4}{i}\oint_V \frac{\color{red}z~dz}{(bz^2+2az+1)^2}$$

you miss a factor $z$ on the numerator.