# Need help evaluating $\int {\frac {dx}{a＋b\cos x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

**Question**

How to evaluate the integral :
$$\int  {\frac {1}{(a＋b\cos x)^2}}\ dx$$

**My attemp :**
$$A＝\frac {\sin(x)}{a＋b\cos(x)}\\
\implies\;\frac {dA}{dx}＝\frac {a\cos(x)＋b}{(a＋b\cos(x))^2}\implies\;\frac {dA}{dx}＝\frac {a}{b}\left({\frac {bcos(x)＋\frac {b^2}{a}}{(a＋b\cos(x))^2}}\right)\\~\\\implies\;\frac {dA}{dx}＝\frac {a}{b}\left({\frac {1}{a＋b\cos(x)}＋\frac {b^2-a^2}{a}\left({\frac {1}{(a＋b\cos(x))^2}}\right)}\right)\\~\\\implies\;\frac {b^2-a^2}{a}\left({\frac {1}{(a＋b\cos(x))^2}}\right)＝\frac {b}{a}\frac {dA}{dx}-\frac {1}{a＋bcos(x)}$$
So
$$\int{\frac {1}{(a＋b\cos x)^2}}\ dx＝\frac {bA}{b^2-a^2}－\frac {a}{b^2-a^2}\int\frac {1}{a＋b\cos x}dx$$

**I need help finding this integral**
$$\int\frac {1}{a＋b\cos x}\ dx$$

Comment: It was just a few hours ago

Comment: Are the limits $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: No, the function is the same but this is an indefinite integral and the other is a definite integral

Comment: Try the Weirestrass substitution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: for such kinds of integrals best take $tan(\frac{x}{2})=t$ and proceed, $\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$=$dx$ and cosx=$\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, and your integral evaluates to $\frac{2}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}arctan(\frac{\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt {a+b}}tan(\frac{x}{2}))$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three distinctive cases shown below
\begin{align}
&\int\frac 1{a＋b\cos x}\ dx\\
=& \int\frac {\csc x}{a\csc x＋b\cot x}\ dx
= \int\frac {a\csc^2x+b \csc x\cot x}{(a\csc x＋b\cot x)^2}\ dx\\
=& \int\frac {-d(a\cot x+b \csc x)}{(a\cot x＋b\csc x)^2+a^2-b^2}\\=&\ 
\begin{cases}
-\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{a\cot x+b \csc x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}&a^2>b^2\\
\frac1 {a\cot x+b \csc x}& a^2=b^2\\
\frac1{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\coth^{-1}\frac{a\cot x+b \csc x}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}&a^2<b^2\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Wonderful! I like it.+1

Answer (score 2):

**Complex version**

Using Euler’s formula, we have
$$
I =\int \frac{1}{a+b \cdot \frac{e^{i x}+e^{-i x}}{2}} d x=2 \int \frac{be^{i x}}{b^2 e^{2 i x}+2 a be^{i x}+b} d x
$$
Letting $t=be^{ix}+a$ transform the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I=\frac{2}{i} \int \frac{d t}{t^2+b^2-a^2} \\
& = \begin{cases}-\frac{2}{i \sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)+C & \text { if } a^2>b^2 \\
-\frac{2}{i t}+C & \text { if } a^2=b^2 \\
\frac{2}{i \sqrt{b^2-a^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)+C &\text { if } a^2<b^2\end{cases} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A standard method for evaluating this kind of integral (more generally, rational functions in $\sin x, \cos x$) is applying the tangent half-angle substitution,
$$x = 2 \arctan t, \qquad dx = \frac{2 \,dt}{1 + t^2},$$
which rationalizes the integral:
$$2 \int \frac{dt}{(a - b) t^2 + (a + b)} .$$
N.b. When making the above substitution, we've implicitly restricted to $x \in (-\pi, \pi)$, which we'll henceforth assume. Since the integrand in $x$ is periodic, knowing an antiderivative on this interval is enough to determine an antiderivative everywhere, even if a global antiderivative is tricky to write down.

How we proceed depends on the sign of the discriminant $\Delta := (0)^2 - 4(a - b)(a + b) = 4(b^2 - a^2)$.

If $\Delta > 0$, then the integral is
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{a + b} \int \frac{dt}{1 + \left(\sqrt\frac{a - b}{a + b} t\right)^2}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}} \arctan \left(\sqrt\frac{a - b}{a + b} t\right) + C\\
&= \boxed{\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}} \arctan \left(\sqrt\frac{a - b}{a + b} \tan \frac{x}{2} \right) + C} .
\end{align}
If $\Delta = 0$, then $b \in \{\pm a\}$. If $b = a$, then the integral is $$\frac{1}{a} \int dt = \frac{1}{a} t + C = \boxed{\frac{1}{a} \tan \frac{x}{2} + C}.$$ If $b = -a$, then the integral is $$\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{dt}{t^2} = -\frac{1}{a t} + C = \boxed{-\frac{1}{a} \cot \frac{x}{2} + C }.$$
Finally, if $\Delta < 0$, then the integrand has discontinuities wherever $t^2 = \frac{b + a}{b - a}$, and the integral is
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{b + a} \int \frac{dt}{1 - \left(\sqrt\frac{b - a}{b + a} t\right)^2}
&= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}} \operatorname{artanh} \left(\sqrt\frac{b - a}{b + a} t\right) + C, & t^2 < \frac{b + a}{b - a} \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}} \operatorname{arcoth} \left(\sqrt\frac{b - a}{b + a} t\right) + C, & t^2 > \frac{b + a}{b - a}
\end{array}
\right. \\
&= \boxed{
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}} \operatorname{artanh} \left(\sqrt\frac{b - a}{b + a} \tan \frac{x}{2}\right) + C, & |x| < 2 \arctan\sqrt{\frac{b + a}{b - a}} \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}} \operatorname{arcoth} \left(\sqrt\frac{b - a}{b + a} \tan \frac{x}{2}\right) + C, & |x| > 2 \arctan\sqrt{\frac{b + a}{b - a}}
\end{array}
\right.} \\
\end{align}